# Removing datapoints from LAS dataset using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, lasd

I'm working with lasd data sets in ArcMap 10.5 and I'm trying to create an density raster from the ground points.

How would I either remove all but the points classed as ground from the las data set or export the datapoints as a vector point layer?

Comment: If you wish to ask a similar question about QGIS 3.2 then please do that in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Put a filter on the LASD dataset in ArcMap.[image]

Then LAS Point Statistics As Raster